# Django rest framework JWT and custom authentication backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a custom user model and have created a custom authentication backend. I am using [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and [django rest framework JWT](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#extending-jsonwebtokenauthentication) for token authentication.

User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=254,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile']
```

Auth backend:

```
class EmailOrMobileAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            if username.isdigit():
                try:
                    user = get_user_model().objects.get(mobile=username)
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        return user
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
            else:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And have added in the settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.EmailOrMobileAuthBackend',)
```

While to log in to django admin site, both the email and mobile number works fine in authenticating the user. However, when I try get the token for the user using [django rest framework JWT](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage), I get an error:

```
curl -X POST -d "email=admin@gmail.com&password=123123" http://localhost/api-token-auth/

"non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
  ]
```

I have also added the custom auth backend class in the Default authentication for Rest framework, but its still not working:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.EmailOrMobileAuthBackend',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

What am I missing? Why is it that its working while loggin to the django admin site, but get error when getting token with django rest framework jwt?

**update**

I have made another auth backend as advised and added it to the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`, but even this is not working.

```
class DrfAuthBackend(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user, None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            if username.isdigit():
                try:
                    user = get_user_model().objects.get(mobile=username)
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        return user, None
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
            else:
                return None
```

Settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.EmailOrMobileAuthBackend',
        'accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.DrfAuthBackend',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

**update**

Changing the `args` in the auth class from `username` to `email` seems to work for obtaining `auth_token` but again its not working to log in to admin site.

```
class EmailOrMobileAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            if email.isdigit():
                try:
                    user = get_user_model().objects.get(mobile=email)
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        return user
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
            else:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: Were you able to finally solve the issue? Got a similar issue where am using `django-rest-framework` with `django-rest-framework-jwt` and I need to allow a user to get a JWT token by logging in via either username or email or mobile_number

Comment: @lukik I am using two authentication backend. One for the django admin and the other for the rest api.

Comment: Are the two backends allowing a user to login via email or mobile? If yes, do you mind sharing how you went about it especially for the rest API? Thanks.

Comment: @lukik Yes, sure. I created two authentication backend (both are basically the same). You can find them [here](https://gist.github.com/robinlery/276e6eceba9cdf5ba9d635332be96159/revisions) and [there](https://gist.github.com/robinlery/1836087fa78941db3e1317acd6efd2b2). And then in the settings I have added [these](https://gist.github.com/robinlery/b0b4a89eb0ef7891f9deb36dab1dc9c6) along the lines.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) for custom authentication backends.

I think your custom authentication backend is breaking it, you may solve it by removing yours from DRF settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Or by fixing yours which is basically not the same as for Django custom authentication, as you should extend from `authentication.BaseAuthentication` and it returns a tuple.

```
from rest_framework import authentication


class DrfAuthBackend(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user, None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            if email.isdigit():
                try:
                    user = get_user_model().objects.get(mobile=email)
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        return user, None
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
            else:
                return None
```

Then use that in the DRF settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.DrfAuthBackend',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

For the Django login:

```
class EmailOrMobileAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            if username.isdigit():
                try:
                    user = get_user_model().objects.get(mobile=username)
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        return user
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    return None
            else:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then for the settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.EmailOrMobileAuthBackend',)
```

Comment: I have tried your advice and updated the question, but its still not working. However, changing the args in the `authentication()` method from `username` to `email` does the work without the need to add it to the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`. But again its not working to log in to admin site.

Comment: [The Django custom authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) does not support email as keyword argument, you should only use it for Django and write a different one for DRF

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file, add the following:

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.email_mobile_auth_backend.EmailOrMobileAuthBackend'